# TSQL Only Select Rows Where Values Are Not Negated By Another Row

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a compound key.  Each row has a value.  No rows with negative values should be returned.  If two rows exist where Key1 and Key2 are identical and the value in one row is the same as the value in the other row * -1, neither rows should be returned. However if a third row exists with the same Key1 and Key2 with a positive value, it should be returned. Here's an example table:

```
Key1    Key2   Key3    Value
----------------------------
1       1      1       500.00
1       1      2      -500.00
1       1      3       500.00
1       2      1       250.00
1       3      1       100.00
1       3      2      -100.00
```

The query result should be:

```
Key1    Key2    Key3   Value
----------------------------
1       1       3      500.00
1       2       1      250.00
```

So what is the query that can give me this result? Thanks!

Additional Information:

@Jacky, 100.00 should not be returned because another row exists wheres Key1 and Key2 are the same, but the value is exact opposite at -100.00.

@Eralper, 1,1,1 and 1,1,2 cancel out each other, but 1,1,3 should be returned.

@Zohar,I am using SQL Server 2014 SP1. Rows where Key1 and Key2 are the same are the only ones that count as a match.

Also, sorry I didn't include this initially, when a row should be returned, it should be the row with the greatest value in the Key3 column.  For example, 1,1,2 cancels out 1,1,1, and 1,1,3 should be returned.

These are tables with lines that our Purchasing department has entered and our users can pay.  For 1,1,1, Purchasing said this line **can** now be paid. Later, on 1,1,2, Purchasing said this **cannot** be paid.  Later, on 1,1,3 Purchasing said this **can** be paid after all.

That's why at this point in time, I can only return the 2 lines shown in the result table.

Comment: Please do share the code that you have attempted to get the desired results.

Comment: only 2 values can get? How about the value of `100.00`?

Comment: What about 1,1,1 ? Should not it be in the list too?

Comment: What version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: Does rows where key1 and key3 are the same or key2 and key3 are the same also counts as a match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
SELECT
    Key1
    ,Key2
    ,Key3
    ,Value
FROM (
        SELECT
              Key1,
              Key2,
              Key3,
              Value,
              SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Key1, Key2, ABS(Value)) as valueSum,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Key1, Key2, ABS(Value) ORDER BY Key3 DESC) as rowNumber
          FROM [Etads].[dbo].[TestTlsc] 
      ) a
WHERE valueSum > 0
    AND rowNumber = 1
```

If the values "cancel out", the sum of all the values will be zero.  Thus the "WHERE valueSum > 0".

ORDERing BY Key3 DESC puts the max Key3 at rowNumber = 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please test following [SQL CTE query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18) on your test environment

As I commented above, I believe 1,1,1 is a candidate for the output list as the below query suggests

I also used Row_Number() SQL function to [Count() with Over clause](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx)

I know this is a complex query, I hated it :) 
But your requirement is a little bit difficult to answer at a glance

I hope it helps,

```
with cteKeys as (
select ROW_NUMBER() over (Order By key1,key2,key3) Id, * from keys
), cteList as (
    select
        k1.Id as key1Id,
        k2.Id as key2Id,         
        k1.key1 as key11,
        k1.key2 as key12,
        k1.key3 as key13,
        k2.key1 as key21,
        k2.key2 as key22,
        k2.key3 as key23,
        k1.value as key1val,
        k2.value as key2val,
        case when   (
                k1.key1 = k2.key1 and 
                k1.key2 = k2.key2 and
                k1.key3 <> k2.key3 
                ) then 110
                when (
                k1.key1 = k2.key1 and 
                k1.key2 <> k2.key2 and
                k1.key3 = k2.key3 
                ) then 101
                when (
                k1.key1 <> k2.key1 and 
                k1.key2 = k2.key2 and 
                k1.key3 = k2.key3 
                ) then 011
        end as match
    from cteKeys k1
    left join cteKeys k2 on 
    (
    k1.key1 = k2.key1 and 
    k1.key2 = k2.key2 and
    k1.key3 <> k2.key3 
    ) or
    (
    k1.key1 = k2.key1 and 
    k1.key2 <> k2.key2 and
    k1.key3 = k2.key3 
    ) or
    (
    k1.key1 <> k2.key1 and 
    k1.key2 = k2.key2 and 
    k1.key3 = k2.key3 
    )
)
--select * from cteList

, cteMatches as (
    select 
        *, 
        count(key2Id) over (partition by key1Id, match) cnt,
        isDeleted0 = case when (count(key2Id) over (partition by key1Id, match)) = 0 then 0 else null end
    from cteList
), resultCTE as (
select *, 
    case when (cnt = 2 and key1val <> -1 * key2val and key1val > 0 and key2val > 0) then 0 end as isDeleted2,
    case when (cnt = 1 and key1val = -1 * key2val) then 1 end as isDeleted1
from cteMatches
)
--select * from resultCTE
, final as (
select * --distinct key1Id, key11,key12,key13 
from resultCTE
where isDeleted0 = 0 

union all

select * --distinct key1Id, key11,key12,key13 
from resultCTE
where isDeleted2 = 0
and not exists (
    select * from resultCTE t where t.key1Id = resultCTE.key1Id and isDeleted1 = 1
)

union all

select * from resultCTE where coalesce(coalesce(isDeleted0,isDeleted2),isDeleted1) is null
)
--select * from cteMatches

select distinct * from cteKeys where Id in (

    select key1Id
    from final

) and Value > 0
```

Here is the output

[image]